# Google spreadsheet to Pandas dataframe via Pydrive without download

Tags: python, pandas, google-drive-api, pydrive

How do I read the content of a Google spreadsheet into a Pandas dataframe without downloading the file?

---

I think [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/) or [df2gspread](https://df2gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) may be good shots, but I've been working with [pydrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/) so far and got close to the solution.

With Pydrive I managed to get the export link of my spreadsheet, either as `.csv` or `.xlsx` file. After the authentication process, this looks like

```py
    gauth = GoogleAuth()
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
    drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
    
    # choose whether to export csv or xlsx
    data_type = 'csv'
    
    # get list of files in folder as dictionaries
    file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'my-folder-ID' in parents and 
    trashed=false"}).GetList()
    
    export_key = 'exportLinks'
    
    excel_key = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    csv_key = 'text/csv'
    
    if data_type == 'excel':
        urls = [ file[export_key][excel_key] for file in file_list ]
    
    elif data_type == 'csv':
        urls = [ file[export_key][csv_key] for file in file_list ]
```

The type of url I get for `xlsx` is

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=my-id&exportFormat=xlsx
```

and similarly for `csv`

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=my-id&exportFormat=csv
```

Now, if I click on these links (or visit them with `webbrowser.open(url)`), I *download* the file, that I can then normally read into a Pandas dataframe with `pandas.read_excel()` or `pandas.read_csv()`, as described [here](https://medium.com/@ammar.nomany.tanvir/read-write-update-drive-excel-file-with-pydrive-f63134120ff9).

#### How can I skip the download, and directly read the file into a dataframe from these links?

I tried several solutions:

- [The obvious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917910/how-can-i-export-pandas-dataframe-to-google-sheets-using-python) `pd.read_csv(url)` gives

```
    pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

Interestingly these numbers (`1, 6, 2`) do not depend on the number of rows and columns in my spreadsheet, hinting that the script is trying to read not what it is intended to.

- The analogue `pd.read_excel(url)` gives

```
    ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
```

and specifying e.g. `engine = 'openpyxl'` gives

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

- [BytesIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611729/getting-google-spreadsheet-csv-into-a-pandas-dataframe) solution looked promising, but

```
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.content
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data))
```

still gives

```
    pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

If I `print(data)` I get hundreds of lines of `html` code

```
    b'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="de">\n  <head>\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n  <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">\n 
    ...
    ...
     </script>\n  </body>\n</html>\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification? In this case, by retrieving the access token from `gauth`, the Spreadsheet is exported as XLSX data, and the XLSX data is put into the dataframe.

#### Modified script:

```py
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={spreadsheetId}&exportFormat=xlsx"
res = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + gauth.attr['credentials'].access_token})
values = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(res.content))
print(values)
```

- In this script, please add `import requests`.
- In this case, the 1st tab of XLSX data is used.
- When you want to use the other tab, please modify `values = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(res.content))` as follows.

  ```
    sheet = "Sheet2"
    values = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(res.content), sheet_name=sheet)
  ```

Comment: Thanks! In the meanwhile I could also get it to work using `gspread` along with `pydrive`. On a side note, I was pleasantly surprised to find an answer by you, since a few minutes ago you made my day with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358444/how-to-format-a-datetime-so-google-sheets-recognise-the-value-as-date-time

Comment: @DavideL Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And also, I'm glad my answer was useful. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike can you please answer my question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027348/how-to-schedule-a-bigquery-run-through-apps-script

Answer (score 1):

I want to contribute an additional option to @Tanaike's excellent answer. Indeed it is quite difficult to successfully get an excel file (.xlsx from drive and *not* a google sheet) into a python environment without publishing the content to the web. Whereas the previous answer uses pydrive and GoogleAuth(), I usually use a different method of authentification in colab/jupyter notebooks. Adapted from [googleapis documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/user-guide.html#identity-tokens). In my environment using BytesIO(response.content) is unnecessary.

```
import pandas as pd

from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

id = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
sheet = 'Sheet12345'

url = f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id={id}&exportFormat=xlsx'

authed_session = AuthorizedSession(creds)
response = authed_session.get(url)

values = pd.read_excel(response.content, sheet_name=sheet)
```