# Read GoogleSheet with multiple sheets into pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-sheets

I want to read google sheet *with multiple sheets* into a (or several) pandas dataframe.

I don't know the sheet names, or the number of sheets in advance.

---

[The trivial attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) fails:

```
def main():
    path = r"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-MlSisrAxhOyKhrz6S08PG68j667Ym7jGExOyytpCSM/edit?usp=sharing"

    pd.read_excel(path)
```

fails with

```
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
```

Trying any [format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) doesn't work.

---

All answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19611729/913098) refer to `.csv`, meaning a single sheet, or knowing the sheet name in advance.

Same goes for the 1st Google hit for "[read google sheet python pandas](https://towardsdatascience.com/read-data-from-google-sheets-into-pandas-without-the-google-sheets-api-5c468536550#:%7E:text=All%20you%20need%20to%20do,a%20url%20pandas%20can%20read.&text=You%20can%20find%20the%20sheet,name%20you%20gave%20your%20sheet.)".

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: Your error says `Excel file format cannot be determined` - are you sure you are reading speradsheets and not excel files?

Answer (score 0):

When your Spreadsheet is publicly shared, in your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO

spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=" + spreadsheetId
res = requests.get(url)
data = BytesIO(res.content)
xlsx = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=data)
for name in xlsx.sheetnames:
    values = pd.read_excel(data, sheet_name=name)

    # do something
```

- In this sample script, the publicly shared Spreadsheet is exported as a XLSX data. And, the exported XLSX data is opened, the sheet names are retrieved. And then, each sheet is put into the dataframe.
- If you want to retrieve the specific sheets, please filter the sheet names from `xlsx.sheetnames`.

#### Note:

- If your Spreadsheet is not publicly shared, this thread might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71278523/7108653)